# How to separate files uploaded on github into folders?

Tags: git, github

I am new to Github, now quite sure how git works, but I feel like I've seen other users having their work separated into folders, and I'd like to do that. It would be within one branch with files I have just uploaded.

I have tried uploading the files within a folder I had created on my computer, but it seemed to be unable to upload a folder. I have also checked the "Add file" >> "Create new file" to check if that would include folder.

Comment: Git repositories generally consist of a hierarchy of nested directories.  If you have a local directory that is a Git repo, you can just create directories within it and create files in those directories.  Then you just add the files at whatever level they are at in the hierarchy, and Git will do the right thing.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to create a new repository with a single file in it that's two levels down in the directory hierarchy:

```
mkdir my_new_repo
cd my_new_repo
git init                         # create a new repository
mkdir -p dir1/dir2               # make a nested pair of dirs
touch dir1/dir2/file1            # create a file in the deeper dir
git add dir1/dir2/file1          # add the file to the git repo
git commit -m"commit message" .  # commit the new file to the repo
```

If you are doing all of this via an IDE or some other graphical interface, then you need to figure out how to perform these same operations using that interface.